# Difference among ID3, C4.5, C5.0

Tags: machine-learning, decision-trees, algorithms

The C4.5 algorithm uses information gain ratio instead of information gain like ID3, and it also adds pruning.

What does C5.0 add more? Is there any example of code? I looked on the web but there is not anything interesting.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C4.5_algorithm#Improvements_in_C5.0/See5_algorithm):

> C5.0 offers a number of improvements on C4.5. Some of these are:[6][7]
>
> - Speed - C5.0 is significantly faster than C4.5 (several orders of magnitude)
> - Memory usage - C5.0 is more memory efficient than C4.5
> - Smaller decision trees - C5.0 gets similar results to C4.5 with considerably smaller decision trees.
> - Support for boosting - Boosting improves the trees and gives them more accuracy.
> - Weighting - C5.0 allows you to weight different cases and misclassification types.
> - Winnowing - a C5.0 option automatically winnows the attributes to remove those that may be unhelpful.

You can download the source code of a single-threaded version from [the official website](https://www.rulequest.com/download.html); it is implemented in C. There is also an unofficial R implementation in the [C50 package](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/C50/) in CRAN. You can also invoke it from Python via [rpy2](https://rpy2.github.io/) following [these steps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41070087/calling-c5-0-in-python).